# Detect machine IP and set a property

Tags: svn, ant

I'm working on an Ant project that involves a Subversion export command.  The svn repo address is a variable in build.xml.

I've set up a read-only svn mirror in the office in order to minimize checkout time and reduce overall build time.

Since the Ant buildfile must run both in the office and on an AWS EC2 build machine, I'm wondering: is there a possibility with Ant to detect the machine IP address, and if it's something like 172.18.30.xx perform a "sed" on the svn variable to adjust the address automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [`<hostinfo>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/hostinfo.html) and [`<condition>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) tasks, something like the below.  This doesn't used "sed", rather it sets the repo address to either one value or another, depending on the IP address of the host running Ant.

```
<hostinfo />
<echo message="IP is ${ADDR4}" />

<condition property="svn_repo"
           value="REPO_URL_1" 
           else="REPO_URL_2">
    <matches string="${ADDR4}" pattern="^172\.18\.30\." />
</condition>
<echo message="${svn_repo}" />
```